# Как перекрасить в другой цвет линии маршрута яндекс карт?

Tags: javascript, html, css, карты, яндекс-карты

На карте хочу перекрасить линии маршрута в другие цвета (зеленый и красный), но не могу обнаружить стили отвечающие за них

```html
<iframe src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/frame/v1/-/CZcurPIL" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменение цвета линий на карте не предусмотрено, вот что можно сделать через конструктор карт (согласно документации):

На карте вы сможете нарисовать:

- метки — подъезды, пункты встречи и т. д.
- линии — улицы, маршруты,
- границы и т. д.  многоугольники (в том числе с внутренним контуром) —
  дома, коттеджные поселки, озера и т. д.

Такую карту вы сможете:

- вставить на сайт, в блог или мобильное приложение, или поделиться с
  друзьями картой, с которой можно взаимодействовать — например,
  перемещать (для этого выберите интерактивный тип карты);
- сохранить и разместить на вашем сайте или в блоге в виде картинки, поделиться ею с друзьями (для этого выберите статический тип карты);
- распечатать или сохранить в виде рисунка (для этого выберите печатный
  тип карты).

Вы сможете сохранить объекты вашей карты в виде файла, который можно использовать:

- для импорта нужных точек в программы-навигаторы,
- для использования совместно с API Яндекс.Карт,
- для просмотра и сохранения данных в других программах (например, в Google Earth).

[Источник информации](https://yandex.ru/support/maps-builder/concept/).